# Should I still try and intern for this startup company after getting directed only to a github repository?

Tags: internship, company-culture, startup, australia

I’m trying to intern as a software developer but getting my foot in the door is next to impossible as our government are cracking down on companies due to exploitation.

I’ve traveled a long way to the city and back and now this startup profit-for-purpose company with no developers as of yet are saying they will give me internship and through that a part time job with other companies in their work hub.

I waited a week for tasks. They later on emailed me and thanked me for my patience but now it’s being 2 weeks.

I met up with them at an event and they directed me to a intern programmer who in turn directed me to a github repository that they made as a side project for the company. So now rather than internship I just got this Github repository that I’m supposed to improve.

I could have done that with any repository and not come all the way to the city just for that. Can I trust this company to come through for me and get me a part time job?

Comment: Where is this happening? Location, please.

Comment: The city would have been enough. probably better delete the company name.

Comment: Brisbane, Queensland.

Comment: Are they paying you?

Comment: @Mawg FYI I was before just mentioning the workhub where the company was. Not the company itself. But still it is better not to be too specific there.

Comment: I think that you are correct there :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They have no developers. They clearly don't have any idea how to treat or help an intern. There is nothing here you can learn, that you could not also learn on your own, with the advantage that if you do it on your own, you get to keep any of the possible spoils or code.

It doesn't sound like there's anything worth pursuing at this company. An internship is about *learning on the job* from *experienced people in your field*. This company appears to offer neither of these things.

Comment: A good summary - they're a bunch of chancers. Keep looking. Meanwhile - What kind of software do you want to develop? What toolset / languages? Try and narrow it down and focus your learning while you look.